# IntelliJ Debugger Gets Completely Lost on Android NullPointerException?

Tags: android, debugging, android-activity, intellij-idea, stack-trace

Android debugging in IntelliJ is generally pretty decent. But the stack trace is worthless for a cause as simple as a NullPointerException within a UI handler lands you in Choreographer.

For example,

### The Cause (null pointer dereference)

```
@Override protected void onDraw (final Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Object nullRef = null;
    nullRef.doSomething();  // crashes here, but not in stack trace
```

### Worthless Stack Trace in Choreographer

[image: Bogus Stack]

### Uncaught Exception in doCallbacks

[image: Choreographer Source]

### Is there a way to see the User code that caused the exception in the Stack Trace?

(other than "Use Eclipse")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch over to logcat, it will show you the full stack trace along with the class and line number where the NullPointerException occurred.

Comment: Ah, the logcat output is delayed until AFTER continuing from the above breakpoint in Choreographer.